# Using JS instigated dialogs in an android webview

Tags: android, mobile

I'm trying to get my webview to show a javascript 'confirm' box, and I'm getting the following exception shrown (from logcat):

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  387): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add         window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@40
5113d8 is not valid; is your activity running?
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at com.playfish.our.app.activity.App$1.onJsConfirm(App.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(  387):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(   60):   Force finishing activity com.playfish.our.app/.activity.App
W/ActivityManager(   60): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4071cfc0 com.playfish.our.app/.activity.App}
```

The code for my dialog is:

```
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), cm.message() + " -- From line "
                    + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                    + cm.sourceId());
            return true;
        }

          @Override
          public void onReachedMaxAppCacheSize(long spaceNeeded, long totalUsedQuota,    WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater)
          {
                quotaUpdater.updateQuota(spaceNeeded * 2);
          }

         @Override
         public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

             new AlertDialog.Builder(App.this)
            .setTitle("Update")
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            result.confirm();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            result.cancel();
                        }
                    })
            .create()
            .show();

            return true;
        }
     });
```

The code isn't very well organised (or good) at the moment, so please don't dwell on that; I'll refactor after it works :)

I think it's something to do with the context passed to the dialog being wrong, and I've found several answers on the web to similar problem, but none of them work for me. I've used other values for the context and none of them worked, e.g. getApplicationContext(), webview.getContext() etc....any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, there's a good chance I'm doing something very stupid as I'm a JS dev with little experience of java.

Comment: Hi. Have you found the answer to this question ?

Comment: Sorry Andrew, no. I'm on a different project now so I doubt I'll be chasing an answer. Good luck in finding one!

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for the response, though, really appreciate taking your time ! :)